# What actually happens when IntelliJ 'updates' a maven repo?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

Using IntelliJ 12, following `Settings->Maven->Repositories`, i noticed that mine were not updated recently. After i selected a repo and waited for a minute or two, they were updated.

I wonder, what actually happened from `IntelliJ's` point of view?

Does it pre-cache content? How often should repos be 'update'd?

Answer (score 6):

IntelliJ IDEA downloads indexes of maven repositories to suggest groupId, artifactId and versions of maven artifact when user edit pom.xml. 
I update repos indexes when I add new repository to the project.